# how to form a regex that will parse the following?

Tags: regex

I need to parse the following line:

```
Action(X,X,Cash(50))Action(Y,Y,Material(30,Car,2))Action(I,I,Cash(50))
```

The output should look like:

```
Action(X,X,Cash(50))
Action(Y,Y,Material(30,Car,2))
Action(I,I,Cash(50))
```

The regex I used is:

```
String tokenRegex = "(Action+\\(([a-zA-Z]+|\\,|([a-zA-Z]+\\(\\d*|[a-zA-Z]+|\\,)\\))+\\))";
```

It fails to parse "Action(Y,Y,Material(30,Car,2))" but works for "Action(X,X,Cash(50))".
What am i doing wrong. What will be the correct regex?

Comment: Why do you have `+` after `Action`? That will allow `Actionnnnnnnn`.

Comment: I am not sure how complex your input is going to be. If `Action` functor can be nested inside another `Action` functor then it will become messy to do with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does it:

```
String tokenRegex = "(Action\\([a-zA-Z]+,[a-zA-Z]+,[a-zA-Z]+\\(\\d+(,([a-zA-Z]+|\\d+))*\\)\\))";
```

I removed some the parentheses that weren't needed for grouping in the regular expression. If you need them for capturing parts of the expression, you'll have to add them back.

Comment: Added a missing backslash, try it now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a regex just do something to the effect of

```
string.replace(")A", ")\nA");
```

Comment: that is if the OP is using java

Comment: That will put a newline between the parens at the end of `Action(X,X,Cash(50))`.

Comment: @anakata perhaps; it was really more a pseudocode type thing.  If he's competent in the language he's working in it should be trivial to translate it as needed